# Trigger Postgres in PgAdmin4 to Execute a python script when a table is appended

Tags: python, postgresql, pgadmin-4

In a postgres database using PgAdmin 4 version 4, I have a table A as follows

```
ID     Name
-------------
001    John Snow
002    Arya Stark
```

I would like to set PgAdmin to execute a simple python script namely status.py to just print out a message for any newly appended row in table A.  My python script look like this

```
print("New rows have been added")
```

I'm trying to learn trigger function in Postgres but i could not figure out how to make it call python.  May I have your suggestions?

Comment: What's the point of printing a message from a Trigger? Who's going to see it? If you're willing to log it into another table / log file or something it would be useful. Just displaying a message is pointless.

Comment: Actually, I have another long python script to execute but it is not convenient to explain. So I just use a simple one to ask in this question